# What words are typically used to refer to vehicles and deliniate between types of vehicles in Latin America

Tags: selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, méxico

I would like to know the words for cars, trucks, vans, pickups, and SUVs in regular Mexican usage. I know car is carro, but is that what a typical Mexican is most likely to use too?

Comment: This question, as worded, is very broad. It could also likely be answered with any Spanish/English dictionary. Can we get you to narrow the question significantly? If you have a *specific* doubt about how to translate a *specific* word or phrase, after consulting standard reference materials, that would be the proper question to ask.

Comment: What am trying to understand is context, if I made the question less broad I risk loosing that context. If I got a response then I could narrow down the question and make it more specific.

Comment: Precisamente por eso es una pregunta que vale la pena, hay tantas posibles respuestas que sería de gran ayuda para todos. Los diccionarios no dicen ciertas palabras y donde se usan o no.

Comment: Thank you for discouraging the use of stack exchange. I've been a member and user for quite some time. I understand the parameters quite well. I'm sure you intentions are good but my opinion is your are not being helpful.

Comment: @DavidSopko: Then you understand why open-ended questions like this don't work well in this Q&A format. There are literally dozens, if not hundreds, of words which can be used to describe different types of vehicles, and in different contexts (formal, slang, etc). Even specifying "every day speech" is not specific enough, as there are still dozens of types of vehicles. To make this question sufficiently narrow, it must focus on a specific word or concept.